# Determine if MKOverlay contains a CLLocationCoordinate2D (or MKMapPoint)

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, mkmapview, overlay

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine if an annotation is inside of MKPolygonView (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios)

I am trying to determine wether a location is contained inside an overlay on my MKMapView.

I have looked at `MKMapRectContainsPoint` and that works if the overlay is a rectangle; using the `boundingMapRect` property of MKOverlay.

The problem is that if the region is not a rectangle the function will still returns true as it looks at the max and minimum coordinates to create the square.

I would really appreciate any help on this!

Thanks!

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios/4354250#4354250

Comment: @aBitObvious:That is exactly what I was looking for! Do you know what is the protocol to award the right answer to you? Can you post that as an answer? or should I post it? Or do I delete the question as it is  "DUPLICATE" I just want to thank you!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  Good question on the protocol here.  I didn't have anything more to add besides a link to the previous answer so I just commented.  You're welcome to answer this or delete it or search/ask on meta to see what people think.  Thanks.