# Intercepting touches on MKOverlay border

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, mkoverlay

One of the functions of program is to select a piece of the map. I do this using MKAnnotations and using a MKPolygonView (with just the border visible) to connect the "dots". (Please take a look at the screenshot below).

[image: MKMapView with MKAnnotationViews connected by the border of a MKPolygonView]

However, I'm trying to find a mechanism so that users can add new pins. This should be done by pressing on a border part of the MKPolygonView and then a new pin is added in the middle of the border.

In order to do this, I have to intercept touches, probably using the UIGestureRecognizer. I have looked at [Touch events on MKMapView's overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436479/touch-events-on-mkmapviews-overlays), which gave me a good lead. The only problem is that this intercepts touches also inside the MKPolygonView. I just need the border.

Is there any way to achieve this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but anyway - one of the possible workarounds is using MKPolyline simultaneously. You could add a MKPolyline, matching MKPolygon border and detect taps on MKPolyline.