# popover to be shown only when overlay is touched

Tags: objective-c

On my map, overlay is updated as and when the user moves. I want to pop up the current location's details only when the OVERLAY is touched not when touched anywhere else on the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an action method, that shows the popover. After that write some code that detects when the overlay is touched. The last step is to make sure the action method that shows the popover is called only when a touch is detected on the OVERLAY.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thats where am struck. Should I explicitly add gesture to the overlay or is the any other easy way to do it?

Comment: Look at this question here. He could not find a way to do it, but he added an annotation to the map where the overlay is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436479/touch-events-on-mkmapviews-overlays If you do not want to add an annotation, one solution is to make a custom annotation and make it transparent.