# Empty CGPath in MKOverlayPathRenderer and MKOverlayPathView

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Path property of `MKOverlayPathView` instance from `MKMapView` always returns nil during all `iOS7.0` betas (from 1 til 5).
Trying to replace `MKOverlayPathView` with new renderers API (`MKOverlayPathRenderer`) has no effect.

```
- (MKOverlayView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
     MKPolygonView *polygonView = [[[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay] autorelease]; // overlay — MKPolygon class
     CGPathRef p = polygonView.path; // not nil
     return [polygonView autorelease];
}

// ... somewhere in main thread
MKPolygonView *polygonOverlayView = (MKPolygonView*)[_mapView viewForOverlay:overlay]; // polygonOverlayView not nil
CGPathRef p = polygonOverlayView.path; // nil
```

Does anyone have this kind of problem?

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014926/detecting-a-point-in-a-mkpolygon-broke-with-ios7-cgpathcontainspoint.