# How to retrieve Map Annotation coordinates?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I'm wanting to have an IBAction center my mapview's region on an annotation.  The annotation is added to the mapview like this:

```
myAnnotation *pinLoc=[[myAnnotation alloc] init];
pinLoc.coordinate = mapview.centerCoordinate;
pinLoc.title = @"Title";
pinLoc.subtitle = @"subtitle";
[mapview addAnnotation:pinLoc];
```

I'd like to retreive it and move the region's center like this somehow:

```
- (IBAction)findPin:(id)sender {

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };

    region.center.latitude = pinLoc.coordinate.latitude;
    region.center.longitude = pinloc.coordinate.longitude;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.001f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
    [mapview setDelegate:self];
}
```

I am also looking for a way to tell if the pin is within a polygon. I've got that working using the user location, but again, I need to retrieve the pin's coordinates to get it working with the pin also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to store a reference to the annotation when you add it.

For example, you could declare a retain property called `pinToRemember` of type `myAnnotation` and after adding the annotation, do this to save it for later:

```
[mapview addAnnotation:pinLoc];
self.pinToRemember = pinLoc;
```

Then in `findPin:`, you would do:

```
if (pinToRemember == nil)
    return;

region.center = pinToRemember.coordinate;
```

Alternatively, you could search through the map view's `annotations` array property and look for the annotation you are interested in by looking for its `title` or some other custom property.  This could be done by using a simple for-loop.

You say you have the "way to tell if the pin is within a polygon" working but this answer may also be useful:
[How to determine if an annotation is inside of MKPolygonView (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios/4354250#4354250)

Comment: Sometimes I can't see the answers that are right in front of me, thanks Anna. Your presence on StackOverflow has saved me countless times already in my early iOS Dev career. I actually am alrdy using your code to determine if a point is within a polygon!