# MKPolygon and point contains

Tags: ios, polygon, kml, mkpolygon

I have a **KML** file that contains all the polygons coordinates for all countries.
Some countries have more than 1 `<coordinates>` tag.
What I am trying to accomplish here is to get a coordinates and find in which polygon is located. I got an idea on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354130/how-to-determine-if-an-annotation-is-inside-of-mkpolygonview-ios) post but my problem is that my algorithm is wrong and returns that my coordinates are located on more than 1 polygons.
This is my code:

```
-(void)parseCoordinates:(NSString*)str{

    coordinatesArray = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    NSInteger coordinatesCount = [coordinatesArray count];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D *cord2d = malloc(sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D) * coordinatesCount);

    for(int i=0; i<coordinatesCount;i++){

        NSString *st = [coordinatesArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([st isEqualToString:@""]) {
            continue;

        }

        NSArray *strArray = [st componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        if ([strArray count]>1) {

            cord2d[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[strArray objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue], [[strArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]);

        }

        strArray=nil;
}

    free(cord2d);

    coordinatesArray = nil;

    MKPolygon* poly2 = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:cord2d count:coordinatesCount];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D mapCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.1274378,-100.9945566);

    MKMapPoint mapPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(mapCoordinate);

    MKPolygonRenderer *polygonView = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc]initWithPolygon:poly2];

    CGPoint polygonViewPoint = [polygonView pointForMapPoint:mapPoint];

    BOOL mapCoordinateIsInPolygon =
    CGPathContainsPoint(polygonView.path, NULL, polygonViewPoint, NO);

    NSLog(@"Country: %@", country);
    NSLog(@"is it inside? %d",mapCoordinateIsInPolygon);

}
```