# Check if coordinates are inside a KML polygon

Tags: swift

I have a KML file which defines a region (or polygon). I would like to make a function that checks if a given coordinate is inside or outside that polygon.

This is the KML if you want to take a look: http://pastebin.com/LGfn3L8H

I don't want to show any map, I just want to return a boolean.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is usually a bad practice to rely on outside sources as those may break and the question loses it's value. Feel free to post codes and details of your problem within your question to allow people to better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Point-in-polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) (PiP) is a very well-studied computational geometry problem, so there are lots of algorithms and implementations out there that you can use. Searching SO will probably find several you can copy-paste, even.

There's a catch, though—you're dealing with polygons on the surface of the Earth... which is a sphere, not the infinite Euclidean plane that most PiP algorithms expect to work with. (You can, for example, have triangles whose internal angles add up to greater than π radians.) So naively deploying a PiP algorithm will give you incorrect answers for edge cases.

It's probably easiest to use a library that can account for differences between Euclidean and spherical (or, more precisely, Earth-shaped) geometry—that is, a mapping library like MapKit. There are tricks [like the one in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732178/957768) that let you convert a `MKPolygon` to a `CGPath` through map projection, after which you can use the `CGPathContainsPoint` function to test against the flat 2D polygon corresponding to your Earth-surface polygon.

Of course, to do that you'll also need to get your KML file imported to MapKit. Apple has [a sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) illustrating how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `GMSGeometryContainsLocation`.

I wrote a method that makes use of the GoogleMapsUtils library's `GMUKMLParser`.

```
func findPolygonName(_ location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    var name: String?
outerLoop: for placemark in kmlParser.placemarks {
    if let polygon = (placemark as? GMUPlacemark)?.geometry as? GMUPolygon {
        for path in polygon.paths {
            if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(location, path, true) {
                name = (placemark as? GMUPlacemark)?.title
                break outerLoop
            }
        }
    }
}
    if let n = name, !n.isEmpty {
        locationLabel.text = n
    } else {
        locationLabel.text = "We do not deliver here"
    }
}
```

This function iterates over the polygon and its path to determine whether the given coordinates are within the path.